# Invoice class for variable pricing

Tags: document-classes

One of my clients uses me for bug fixes and feature extensions on various websites. We agreed to a pricing structure that is some sum per hour for the first 50 hours of work in a month, and a lower sum per hour afterwards. Is there an invoice class that can deal with this, or do I need to roll my own?

Comment: Easier to roll your own http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44216/963

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have two different fees, why don't you simply say

1. Basic charge , 50 units, price per unit
2. Reduced charge, x unites, price per unit

That way, it is transparent to your customer.

Otherwise, I could think to build a `\FeeStaged{...}{...}{...}{...}` command which accepts a set of different remuneration levels plus the hour limitation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I [marked your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) with backticks.