# Is there a counter or variable that can be used to store non-integers?

Tags: counters, calculations

I'm working on an invoice document which has a 'Grand Total' at the end of the document after some rows of invoice items. As such, I need to keep a running count of the total for each row. Using the traditional `\newcounter` and `\addtocounter` counter doesn't work as this doesn't accept decimals, which currency often has.

What would be the recommended way to create and maintain a variable that can have numbers added to it that contain decimals?

Comment: work in pennies, and put the decimal points in when printing?

Comment: @Thruston My mom always told me to "count your pennies and the dollars take care of themselves."  I never knew she had familiarity with LaTeX.

Comment: See this for an answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44216/963, uses the 'fp' package. If is ok with you please  close this as duplicate.

Comment: I think Thruston's suggestion is the best idea. There is a `calc` package for calculations with decimal points, but it involves truncation at the end of single operations, which you surely do not want. Still, you may be interested in seeing what it offers.

Comment: But then I hadn't yet seen the other comment with the link.

Comment: Decimal calculation is sometimes used in the form of lengths, and then the unit of measure is stripped when printing (using something like `\strip@pt` from the [LaTeX kernel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)).

Comment: Can you show a simple example of what you have in mind?

Comment: Have a look on the `calculator` package, it eases the usage of floating point calculations, but it is not possible with counters, however, in a direct way

Comment: Alternatively have a look on the `invoices` package. It might do what you request

Comment: Yiannis's answer using the fp package worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a very 'easy' approach with `expl3` syntax and its `\fp_...` variables.

Since the question is not totally clear, I provided some macros for adding and subtracting as well as resetting and displaying the total sum.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \g_total_sum_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddValue}{m}{
  \fp_gadd:Nn \g_total_sum_fp {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SubValue}{m}{
  \fp_gsub:Nn \g_total_sum_fp {#1}
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\ResetSum}{}{
  \fp_zero:N \g_total_sum_fp 
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplaySum}{}{
  \fp_to_decimal:N \g_total_sum_fp
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}


\AddValue{4.5}

\DisplaySum

\AddValue{10.5}
\DisplaySum

\AddValue{2}
\DisplaySum

\AddValue{17}
\DisplaySum

\AddValue{-2}
\DisplaySum

\ResetSum
\DisplaySum

\end{document}
```

[image]

A related question can be found here: [Number formatting, addtocounter and calc package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305415/number-formatting-addtocounter-and-calc-package)

Comment: @HarishKumar: Hello Harish, you're back? Happy new year!

Comment: Hi Christian: I am always there ;). I am on and off but unfortunately the frequency is very low. :

Comment: @HarishKumar: Too low, in my opinion. We miss you

Answer (score 2):

For counting of money you can use normal TeX counter. This counter stores values in pennies.

```
\newcount\tmpvar
\newcount\myvar 

\def\addvar#1#2 {\let\tmp=#1\addvarA #2.\end}
\def\addvarA#1.#2\end{\advance\tmp by #100
   \ifx;#2;\else\ifx.#2\else\addvarB#1.#2\fi\fi}
\def\addvarB#1.#2#3.{\advance\tmp by \ifnum#1<0-\fi #2#3\ifx;#3;0\fi\space}
\def\printvar#1{\tmpvar=#1%
   \divide\tmpvar by100
   \ifnum\tmpvar=0 \ifnum#1<0-\fi\fi \the\tmpvar
   \multiply\tmpvar by-100 \advance\tmpvar by#1%
   \ifnum\tmpvar=0 \else.%
      \ifnum\tmpvar<0 \tmpvar=-\tmpvar \fi
      \ifnum\tmpvar<10 0\fi \the\tmpvar
   \fi
}

% test:

\myvar=0
\addvar\myvar  3.45
\addvar\myvar -5
\addvar\myvar  1.5
\printvar\myvar  % -0.05 is printed

\myvar=0
\addvar\myvar  2.3
\printvar\myvar  % 2.3 is printed

\myvar=0
\addvar\myvar 123.
\addvar\myvar   0.01
\printvar\myvar  % 123.01 is printed
```

Comment: What would be needed to use a macro value as the value to add? For example:


```
\def\foo{3.14}
\myvar=0
\addvar\myvar\foo
\printvar\myvar % I should expect this to produce 3.14
```