# Number formatting, addtocounter and calc package

Tags: formatting, counters, calculations

I have been having troubles with the following issue:

I am making an invoice template in `LaTeX`. I use `\addtocounter` to calculate values like subtotal, tax and total. This works fine, until the value contains a decimal number (which happens often in invoices of course). To counter this, I use the `calc` package in order to do: `\addtocounter{subtotal}{\real{19.95}}`. This works fine too.

However, when I load the package `numprint` or `siunitx` so that my numbers are correctly formatted on the decimal in the invoice table, I get the error:

```
/Invoices/A4.tex:22 Missing number, treated as zero \addtocounter{subtotal}{\real{19.95}}
```

As soon as I remove those two packages, all works fine again.

**My question:** is there a way to format numbers in a table while still being able to calculate the totals using decimal numbers?

You can find the code here: https://www.overleaf.com/4958478dccytf#/15308055/
Note that the code includes an `invoice.cls` and that an example of the problem can be found in the main page on line 22 and 23.

Comment: `\real` does not provide integer numbers, apparently, which are desperately needed by counter registers

Comment: @ChristianHupfer but this is how they instruct me to do it, see http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/calc.pdf (page 3).

Comment: Well, apparently the truncating doesn't work any longer then

Comment: Perhaps a `LaTeX 3` method is more appropiate here!

Comment: See my answer to this question for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196373/is-there-a-counter-or-variable-that-can-be-used-to-store-numbers-with-decimals

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the help. I have added your suggestion (see: https://www.overleaf.com/4958478dccytf#/15308070/) but as you can see the total does not add up correctly. Any insights? Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: Not yet -- I will try to come back to it (later on)

Answer (score 1):

The `\real` macro seems to need `arithmetics` desperately,  i.e. use `1*\real{19.95}` etc.

But it will be truncated anyway!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{calc}


\newcounter{foo}
\begin{document}

\addtocounter{foo}{5*\real{1.7}}

\thefoo

\end{document}
```

Related: [Is there a counter or variable that can be used to store non-integers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196373/is-there-a-counter-or-variable-that-can-be-used-to-store-numbers-with-decimals)