Compute the sum of non-integer counters at the beginning of the document
I'd like to compute the sum of non-integer counters at the beginning of a document. How can I do this ?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \g_total_sum_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddValue}{m}{
  \fp_gadd:Nn \g_total_sum_fp {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SubValue}{m}{
  \fp_gsub:Nn \g_total_sum_fp {#1}
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\ResetSum}{}{
  \fp_zero:N \g_total_sum_fp 
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplaySum}{}{
  \fp_to_decimal:N \g_total_sum_fp
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\begin{document}

\DisplaySum % How can I print 3.5 here ?
\AddValue{1.5}
\AddValue{2}

\end{document}


\fpeval (→ ltnews35.pdf and usrguide.pdf) and write either the single points or the result to the aux file to be read in the next run (→ https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115932/277964).

BTW: If you want to typeset exercises or similar and show and sum the point for each exercise/question, note that there are already several package for this on CTAN. And please make clear, whether your problem is the summation of non-integers (floating point or fix point numbers) or to use the result at the beginning instead of at the end of the document, because you should always focus on one question.

Working with non-integer counters prevents the use of existing packages and tools. The two issues are thus indissociable.

That's not correct. For using something, before it is known see the last link in my first comment. It explains, how to do this. This is different from summation of floating points, which is a LaTeX kernel feature as explained in the first two links of my first comment. And you've already set tag [tag:expl3], so you could do the summation also using l3pf.

But I've found this topic (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196373/is-there-a-counter-or-variable-that-can-be-used-to-store-non-integers), so I can simplify my question.

So you've proofed yourself, that summation can be answered independent from storing something to be used in the next LaTeX run.

Yes, you're right.

As shown in On the basics of writing to & reading from auxiliary files you have to store the result in the aux file to be read while the next LaTeX run. Because the answer there already shows how to write to the aux file using LaTeX2e, here an example, how to do this using LaTeX3 functions.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \g_total_sum_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddValue}{m}{
  \fp_gadd:Nn \g_total_sum_fp {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SubValue}{m}{
  \fp_gsub:Nn \g_total_sum_fp {#1}
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\ResetSum}{}{
  \fp_zero:N \g_total_sum_fp 
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplaySum}{}{
  \fp_to_decimal:N \g_total_sum_fp
}

\hook_gput_code:nnn { enddocument/afterlastpage } { total/sum }
  {
    \iow_now:ce { @auxout }
      {
        \token_to_str:N \gdef \token_to_str:N \LastRunSum
        { \fp_to_decimal:N \g_total_sum_fp }
      }
  }

\newcommand*{\LastRunSum}{???}

\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\begin{document}

\LastRunSum
\AddValue{1.5}
\AddValue{2}

\end{document}

needs at least 2 LaTeX runs to result in:


Thanks, it works perfectly !

@jowe_19 I've changed the answer, to use a more expl3 syntax for writing to the aux.
