# Non-integer valued counter increment for h2020proposal.cls

Tags: counters

The question I have has already been answered here: [Nice looking invoices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/nice-looking-invoices/44216#44216). However, the code I have to modify using this answer is not easy for me to interpret. I could probably figure it out eventually, but I am working under a tight deadline and can't afford thinking and learning time. So a quick fix would be much appreciated.

The original code, from h2020proposal.cls 2015/08/06 version V1.0, is this:

```
\newcommand{\@personmonths}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{@wptotgroups}
  \addtocounter{@wp\arabic{@wpcount}totpm}{#2}
  \setcounter{@pmpnum}{\getPnum{#1}}
  \addtocounter{@p\arabic{@pmpnum}totpm}{#2}
  \expandafter\xdef\csname
  @pmParticipant\arabic{@pmpnum}WP\arabic{@wpcount}\endcsname{#2} 
}
```

The idea is that argument 2 of this command must be an integer or the calc package will give an error. However, I need to pass a non-integer argument, like 7.8 or 2.4 etc. At the link above they show how to use the fp package to work with such non-integer arguments. I wonder if anyone can modify the above code for me, using the fp package.

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide a compilable document such that we don't have to glue code together then.

Comment: it's unrelated to calc; a counter can only hold integers so you would have to modify the code you have not shown to replace every use of the counter `{@p\arabic{@pmpnum}totpm}` or (often simpler) just multiply by 10 and use 78, 24 as values, then just divide by 10 again for final printing.