# Invoice where VAT is included in the products listed (as often seen on a shopping website for instance)

Tags: formatting, numbering, invoice

I would like to have an invoice that lists products with VAT prices (not without and adding the VAT later), shows total sum including VAT and then there is simply one line saying how much the VAT is. In short, more like a common receipt.

I have tried a lot of templates, but can not find this functionality. What I mean is if I would set VAT to 24% for instance and I have three products that is 30 euro including VAT it would list these products at 30 euros three times under each other, show total price as 90 euro and have one line mentioning that prices includes VAT 21.60 euro.

This format looks very good, except the VAT issue, since now these three products get listed as 30 euro without VAT and then it adds VAT in the end to the total price:

```
\documentclass[english]{letter}
\usepackage{invoice}
\usepackage{babel}
\address{Company name \\\\Street 5 \\34328 Somewhere \\+47000000 \\mail@somedomain.xyz}
\signature{// From me}
\date{Date: \today}

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{ }
    \opening{Invoice number: 500 \\Account number: XXX XXXX XXXX\\Payment time: 14 days}
    \begin{invoice}{Euro}{24}
      \ProjectTitle{Some service}
      \Fee{Product 1} {30} {1}
      \Fee{Product 2} {30} {1}
      \Fee{Product 3} {30} {1}
    \end{invoice}
    \closing{Thank you for your order! :)}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Added a photo from an online shop that does this (in that example the prices are 29.90, but the idea is the same).
[image: example from online shop]

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Do you want this VAT line to appear automatically (like if you scripted it with Lua or Python or some such thing) or is it a presentation issue?

Comment: @Plergux Added a photo to my post from an online shop that does what I want. I want VAT to appear, but not that the products are listed as price without VAT as it is now and VAT getting added to the total sum. What I want is prices are listed with VAT and the end sum is shown as those prices added together, and there is one extra line saying what the total VAT of the order is like this: 
`Product 1 30 euro Product 2 30 euro Product 3 30 euro  Total sum: 90 euro Prices include 21.60 euro VAT`

Comment: You might get some inspiration on how to do something like this from the answers here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/nice-looking-invoices